$(a, b) ∗ (c, d) = (ac − 2bd, bc + ad)$ Find all pairs (a,b,c,d) when $(a, b) ∗ (c, d) = (3, 7)$ Question from STEMS (by Cmi) Year 2020 involving NT
The Question is

Let ∗ be a binary operation on $\mathbb{Z^2}$ defined as follows:
$(a, b) ∗ (c, d) = (ac − 2bd, bc + ad)$.
Find the number of solutions to the equation: $(a, b) ∗ (c, d) = (3, 7)$
 A. 32
 B. $\infty$
 C. 16
 D. 0

My thoughts on this question:
since $(a, b) ∗ (c, d) = (ac − 2bd, bc + ad)$
Thus $ac-2bd = 3$ and $bc+ad = 7$
Now the thing is that in $ac-2bd = 3$, ac must be odd thus a, c both must be odd and thus in the equation $bc+ad = 7$ where a,c are both odd thus either of b or d must be even
And I am not able to proceed after this please correct me.

Hint: $(a + b \sqrt{-2})(c+d\sqrt{-2})$ is equal to?

@CalvinLin Thank you for your insightful hint; it was immensely helpful

Following the hint of Calvin Lin, we see that if we map the ordered pair $(a,b)$ to the number $\varphi(a,b)=a+b\sqrt{-2}$, then our operation becomes multiplication.  Namely, $$\varphi(a,b)\varphi(c,d)=(a+b\sqrt{-2})(c+d\sqrt{-2})=(ac-2bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt{-2}=\varphi((a,b)*(c,d)).$$
Thus, we can rephrase the problem as "How many ways are there to factor $3+7\sqrt{-2}$ in the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$?"
Given a complex number, we can take its square modulus (which we will call the norm), which will be a positive whole number for number of the form we are looking at.  Namely, $|\varphi(a,b)|^2=a^2+2b^2$.  As a starting point, we take norms.  If $(a,b)*(c,d)=(3,7)$, then $(a^2+2b^2)(c^2+2d^2)=3^2+2\cdot 7^2=107$.  Because 107 is a prime number, one of these factors must be $\pm 1$, but since the norm cannot be negative, it must be $1$.
The only solutions to the equation $a^2+2b^2=1$ are $(a,b)=(\pm 1,0)$.  Thus there will be 4 solutions, two where $\varphi(a,b)=\pm 1$, and two where $\varphi(c,d)=\pm 1$.
I'm a little concerned that this isn't one of the listed answers, but I cannot see a flaw in the logic.

Thanks for your solution, I understood everything from it.

@Macavity For each viable $(a,b)$ pair, there is exactly one corresponding $(c,d)$ pair, for if $(a+b\sqrt{-2})(c+d\sqrt{-2})=(3+7\sqrt{-2})$, then $(c+d\sqrt{-2})=\frac{3+7\sqrt{-2}}{(a+b\sqrt{-2})}$. The norm computation shows that $x=3+7\sqrt{-2}$ must be irreducible, and the only units are $\pm 1$, so the only factorizations of $x$ are $1\cdot x, -1 \cdot (-x), x\cdot 1, (-x) \cdot (-1)$

Your counting is correct +1, I somehow looked only at  solutions to the Norm equation.  Time to sleep.
